# Display few cells inside table view and scroll the rest

Tags: ios, uitableview

Inside my `UITableView` I have 2 types of cells lets say A and B.
Initially, my table shows only cells of type A and when the user taps on any cell, I display a list of type B cells to give sort of a drop-down effect. Now the issue is when I tap on a cell of type A it's drop-down may have a large number of type B cells, so what I want to do is limit the number of cells in the dropdown to 3 and then scroll the rest of them in the same position and then have the list of type A cells after that. I have no idea how to do this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell. Very bad user experience though. Scroll inside a scroll !!! Not a great UX

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Any other way you would suggest?

Comment: Differentiate A cells as section header and show B cells as a cells that section. And don't have any internal scrolling. Provide mechanism for user to expand and collapse section that way when interested user will open up a section and continues with selection if user figures out he tapped wrong section header user will collapse the opened section and goes on to open next section

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set bellow constraint in your **internal tableview** that is collapse and expand.

[image]

Comment: internal tableview ? Do you mean adding another tableview for the drop-down, since currently I just have one.

Comment: If you want to limit numbers of cells to display then you need to add sub tableview otherwise in same table you can limit it by setting `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` then problem with this will be there will only be 3 rows and rest of it will be ignored